# Pass variables to SQL query LIMIT sql Pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas, variables

I have two variables i have declared and asigned values to, I want to pass them to an sql query limits in python. Below is what i have tried so far. Any help will be very much appreciated

```
limitstart = 10
limitend = 100

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT NUMBERS FROM `table` LIMIT '{limitstart}', '{limitend}'", con=dbConnection)
```

I am getting a syntax error. I would want the query to eventually be

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT NUMBERS FROM `table` LIMIT 10, 100", con=dbConnection)
```

But i need to pass the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just make a string of command so try something like

`df = pd.read_sql("SELECT NUMBERS FROM table LIMIT " + str(limitstart) + ", "+str(limitend),con = dbConnection)`

Comment: Note that you should never use this method with user-supplied data, due to possible [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 you're missing `f` before your query and have unnecessary `'`:

```
limitstart = 10
limitend = 100

df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT NUMBERS FROM `table` LIMIT {limitstart}, {limitend}", con=dbConnection)
```